# Adding a new field to the neural network struct in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

can anyone tell me is it possible to add a new field to the 'network' structure in MATLAB?

I've tried with this:

```
net = setfield(net,'tr',tr);
```

but I get this error:

> Reference to non-existent field 'tr'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net` is not a regular structure, but an instance of a class.

You can't just add arbitrary fields to an object.

```
>> net = feedforwardnet(4);
>> isobject(net)
ans =
     1
>> class(net)
ans =
network
```

Looking at the object, there is a `userdata` property which provides a place for users to add custom information to a network object.

```
>> net.userdata.tr = rand(10);
>> net.userdata
ans = 
    note: 'Put your custom network information here.'
      tr: [10x10 double]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064054/1714410) pointed out, `net` is an object and not a struct and therefore you **cannot** add a field to it.
What you can do is create your own struct, with `net` as a field in it

```
>> myNet.net = net;
>> myNet.tr = tr;
```